# Windows 7 hangs shortly after startup

Tags: windows-7, freeze

My computer recently started freezing a couple minutes after startup sometimes, but sometimes wouldn't even make it pass the loading screen before freezing. It doesn't seem to matter what I do, play games, surf the net, or not do anything at all - it still freezes all the same. Both keyboard and mouse do not work as well.

Things I have tried and failed:

- booting up in safe mode
- using Avast instead of AVG because I heard AVG may be the cause
- switching my RAM to another slot (this actually helped to lengthen the time it took before freezing - in the first slot, my computer freezes even before reaching the desktop screen, now it takes about 20-30mins to freeze)
- cleaning the fans

There is one more problem which may be related to this. My USB mouse does not work and does not light up at all until replugging.

I am guessing that this is a hardware problem, since the same thing happens in safe mode. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Test your motherboard memory with Memtest86.  http://www.playtool.com/pages/memtest/memtest.html

Comment: Also, get speedfan to see if it is overheating http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php

Comment: Could it be the ram itself that has gone bad? You might try picking up another ram chip and switching it out.

Comment: I have tried Memtest86 twice, the first time it ran for 12hours before it hung, and the second time only 5 minutes. Is the test supposed to run for so long? As for the speedfan test, it seems like my fan is normal. I will try switching out the ram today. Thanks.

Comment: The memtest86 ran with multiple errors before hanging. I have tried switching out the ram, but the problem persists.